# How to convert an address from IPv4 to IPv6

Tags: java, ipv6

Is this possible? How can you convert an ipv4 to an ipv6 address?

a few example from here:

```
0.0.0.0   -> ::
127.0.0.1 -> ::1
```

I'm searching a solution in Java.

Thanks,

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is no IPv4 to IPv6 mapping that is meaningful. things like 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1 are special cases in the spec, so they have equivalent meaning. But given an IPv4 address it tells you nothing about what its specific IPv6 address would be. You can use a DNS lookup to see if a given IP address resolves to a host which in turn resolves to an IPv6 address in addition to an IPv4 address, but the DNS server would have to be configured to support that for the specific machine.

Comment: In a dual-stack system, there is actually a mapping from IPv4 to IPv6, in the ::ffff:XXXX:XXXX space; this is typically displayed as "::ffff:192.168.1.1" -- therefore there is a meaningful representation of IPv4 addresses in the IPv6 address space.

Comment: @DoktorJ, I don't think that was the question. I think the request was for a proper IP6 address, not a way to reference an IP4 address on an IP6 stack.

Comment: @DoktorJ But unless you have a kind of routing facillity, this mapping doesn't really help you.

Comment: I disagree with the tone: I have seen IPv4 addresses mapped to IPv6 in several applications where the developer wanted to have all their addresses in a uniform format for purposes of sorting, searching, etc, and without exception it's ::ffff:0:0/96.  I don't know if it's strictly meaningful, but it's certainly useful. Wikipedia is pretty good on the trade-offs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4-mapped_IPv6_addresses

Answer (score 22):

Hybrid dual-stack IPv6/IPv4 implementations typically support a special class of addresses, the IPv4-mapped addresses. For more check the following link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4-mapped_IPv6_addresses

For converting IPv4 to mapped IPv6, you can use the following:

```
String ip = "127.0.0.1"; 
String[] octets = ip.split("\\.");
byte[] octetBytes = new byte[4];
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            octetBytes[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(octets[i]);
}

byte ipv4asIpV6addr[] = new byte[16];
ipv4asIpV6addr[10] = (byte)0xff;
ipv4asIpV6addr[11] = (byte)0xff;
ipv4asIpV6addr[12] = octetBytes[0];
ipv4asIpV6addr[13] = octetBytes[1];
ipv4asIpV6addr[14] = octetBytes[2];
ipv4asIpV6addr[15] = octetBytes[3];
```

Also check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6to4)

Answer (score 7):

There used to be a reserved address space in IPv6 for IPv4 addresses, where you simply prefixed the IPv4 address with 96 0-bits. E.g. `192.168.10.13 -> ::C0A8:0A0D`. As I know this has been deprecated, and there's no direct conversion available anymore.

Comment: I think there are still IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses which were not deprecated. Your example in this scheme would be ::ffff:c0a8:0a0d. The one with 0s in it was called IPv4-compatible IPv6 addresses.

Answer (score 4):

**IPv6 is IPv4 compatible.**

An IPv4 address : example 192.168.99.1

Step1 >

Divide the first octet (192) by 16 (since Hex is a Base-16)
IE : 192/16 = 12 times exactly with 0 left over
– 12 in Hex is represented as C
– 0 (zero) in Hex is, you guessed it, 0
Thus 192 in HEX is **C0**

Step2 >

Repeat step 1 with the second octet (168),
IE : 168/16 = 10 times with 8 left over because 10*6 = 160,
– 10 in HEX is A
– 8 in HEX is 8
Thus 168 in HEX is **A8**

Step3 >

Repetition rules!!! Third octet (99)
IE : 99/16 = 6 times with 3 left over
– 6 in HEX is 6
– 3 in HEX is 3
Thus 99 in HEX is **63**

Step4 >

Last octet
IE : 1/16 = 0 times with 1 left over
– 0 in HEX is, yeah it is 0
– 1 in HEX is 1
Thus 1 in HEX is **01**

So the IPv4 address of 192.168.99.1, represented in the IPv6 address portion would be **C0A8:6301**. However you have to use lower case and add all the missing bytes IPv6, so the correct code is:

**::c0a8:6301**

or you can use a syntax now always accepted:

**::192.168.99.1**

So in the end a IPv6 address can be the old address with the **::** chars before the old address.

Comment: `::192.168.99.1` representation is deprecated, must be `::ffff:192.168.99.1'. See [Wikipedia - IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4-mapped_IPv6_addresses).

Answer (score 3):

There are numerous methods to map IPv4 to IPv6.  For most such methods, the converted IPv4 address is placed in the lower 4 bytes of the 16 byte IPv6 address.

[The IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) has methods to assist with many of the most common ways of converting IPv4 to IPv6.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager of that library.

For instance, given an IPv4 address you can convert to IPv6 as shown, using IPv6-mapping conversion:

```
IPv6Address ipv6Address = new IPAddressString("1.2.3.4").getAddress().toIPv4().
    getIPv4MappedAddress();
System.out.println(ipv6Address); // ::ffff:102:304
System.out.println(ipv6Address.toMixedString()); // ::ffff:1.2.3.4
```

With an IPv6Address instance you can check if the address is IPv4 mapped, IPv4 compatible, IPv4 translated, and so on (those are some of the many possible ways IPv6 represents IPv4 addresses).  Afterwards, you can convert back to to IPv4.

```
if(addr.isIPv4Compatible() || addr.isIPv4Mapped()) {
    IPv4Address derivedIpv4Address = ipv6Address.getEmbeddedIPv4Address();
    byte ipv4Bytes[] = ipv4Address.getBytes();
    ...
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is the conversion code in Javascript

```js
/** IPV4 CIDR to IPV6 CIDR conversion **/
function covertIPv6(x){
let ipV4 = x;
let address = ipV4.split('/');
let classValues = [];

if(address.length){
  classValues = address[0].split('.');
}
if(classValues.length){  
  let str = classValues.reduce((acc, val, ind)=>{
    let mod = +val >= 16 ? +val%16 : +val;
    let divider = +val >= 16 ? (val-mod)/16 : 0;
    const hexaCode = (hexaVal)=>{
      switch(hexaVal){
      case 10:
        hexaVal = 'A';
        break;
      case 11:
        hexaVal = 'B';
        break;
      case 12:
        hexaVal = 'C';
        break;
      case 13:
        hexaVal = 'D';
        break;
      case 14:
        hexaVal = 'E';
        break;
      case 15:
        hexaVal = 'F';
        break;
      default:
        hexaVal = hexaVal;
        break;
    }
      return hexaVal;
    }
    mod = hexaCode(mod);
    divider = hexaCode(divider);
    return ind === 1 ? `${acc}${divider}${mod}:`:`${acc}${divider}${mod}`
  },'')
  return `2002:${str}::/${address[1]}`;
}
  return "Invalid Address";
}

// Run the function

console.log(covertIPv6("0.0.0.0/12"));
```