# How to calculate an IPv6 IP Number?

Tags: ip, ipv6, ipv4, geoip

I'm adding GeoIP tracking to WCF Web Service using MaxMinds' GeoIP Lite Country. All works well for their IPv4 database but they don't give any samples to calculate an IPv6 IP Number. I've contacted them and they said to use a search engine.

Anyone have a sample they're willing to share? Any language will do.

Comment: To tell the truth, I do not really understand the question (what could be "to calculate an IPv6 IP number"?) and I'm far from certain that Kyle Rozendo's reply is on-topic.Please provide more details.

Comment: If you don't understand then why post?

Comment: I would like to second @bortzmeyer's comment. It's really unclear here exactly what you're trying to achieve. I'm guessing that if you got a better grasp on clearing what the problem is in your own mind, then you'd have a better chance of solving the problem.

Comment: well, that's obvious: I post to explain to the OP why he has so few answers and what he can improve.

Comment: How are you calculating an IPv4 IP Number?

Answer (score 1):

Its not a duplicate question per se, but from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555591/how-to-convert-an-address-from-ipv4-to-ipv6):

> There is no IPv4 to IPv6 mapping that
>   is meaningful. things like 0.0.0.0 and
>   127.0.0.1 are special cases in the spec, so they have equivalent meaning.
>   But given an IPv4 address it tells you
>   nothing about what its specific IPv6
>   address would be. You can use a DNS
>   lookup to see if a given IP address
>   resolves to a host which in turn
>   resolves to an IPv6 address in
>   addition to an IPv4 address, but the
>   DNS server would have to be configured
>   to support that for the specific
>   machine.

Comment: > But given an IPv4 address it tells you nothing about what its specific IPv6 address would be.

Not entirely true. There are a variety of IPv6 address formats that allow IPv4 addresses to be embedded within them, so there is a surjective mapping from a distinguished subset of IPv6 addresses to IPv4 addresses.

In general, what the poster wants is for the geolocator to support IPv6 natively.