# Convert Expanded(long form) IPv6 to IPv4 in java

Tags: java, ip, ipv6, ipv4

I've been trying for hours now to find a library or try to do it with java-core.

I'm trying to convert `Expanded IPv6` to `IPv4` but none of the googled methods does not work.

Also tried this library. https://github.com/seancfoley/IPAddress

Without much success.

Is it even possible?

To understand what I mean. For example, if you Google `what is my ip`, then Google will show you your IP in the `Expanded IPv6` format.

Or you can look at this site: https://whatismyipaddress.com

How can the string (IPv6 long format) be converted to IPv4 in java?

Comment: What makes you think that is even possible? IPv6 and IPv4 addresses are different things.

Comment: The fact, that it should be simple and I cannot find the solution.

Comment: Ipv6 and ipv4 are two totally different things. You cannot convert one into the other

Comment: "it should be simple" - citation needed.

Comment: I didn't tell you, I guessed!

Comment: IPv4 and IPv6 are two separate, incompatible protocols. It would be like trying to convert IPv4 to IPX, or IPv6 to AppleTalk. They are simply different network protocols. You cannot mix them, and you cannot convert one to the other.

Comment: @JDev, have a look at the _[InetAddress](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/net/InetAddress.html)_ class.  The _[Inet6Address](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/net/Inet6Address.html)_ class offers a _[isIPv4CompatibleAddress](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/net/Inet6Address.html#isIPv4CompatibleAddress())_ method.  From there you're simply taking the last 4 bytes to compose an _IPv4_.

Comment: @Reilas, the IPv4-Compatible addresses have been deprecated for almost 20 years. See _[RFC 4291, IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture, 2.5.5.1. IPv4-Compatible IPv6 Address](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4291#section-2.5.5.1)_: "_The 'IPv4-Compatible IPv6 address' is now deprecated because the current IPv6 transition mechanisms no longer use these addresses._"

Comment: @RonMaupin, strange, take a look at the source as well, _https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/net/Inet6Address.java#L297_.

Comment: @Reilas, that library seems woefully out of date. It even includes Site-Local addresses that were deprecated in favor of ULA: "_Site-local addresses are now deprecated as defined in [SLDEP]_," but there is nothing to check for ULA. It does include IPv4-Mapped addresses: "_In InetAddress and Inet6Address, it is used for internal representation; it has no functional role. Java will never return an IPv4-mapped address. These classes can take an IPv4-mapped address as input, both in byte array and text representation. However, it will be converted into an IPv4 address._"

Comment: @RonMaupin, interesting.   I found the relevant _RFC_, [3879](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3879).  It appears to just be a _"proposed standard"_ and advises to refer to _[STD 1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7101#section-3)_ for the _"state and status of [the] protocol"_.  Here, _STD 1_ is defined as _"... in an abnormal state since RFC 5000 was published."_.  This would explain the lack of action on _Java_'s half; you can't amend the standard if it cannot define a state.  They should re-define it as a _notation_, and not a _syntax_.

Comment: @Reilas, read [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/755655/324849) about RFC status, and then look at the _[IANA IPv6 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv6-special-registry/iana-ipv6-special-registry.xhtml)_ where Site-Local addressing has been removed, although ULA is now included.

Comment: @Reilas, you may find my [IP Calculator](https://github.com/rmaupin/IPvX) for both IPv4 and IPv6 interesting. There is all the source code, and you should read the PDF, including the last part that explains the methods. The IP library has some very good regular expressions for both IPs. The calculator also has some fields that provide information about the address, including the various multicast scopes and other address ranges and scopes.

Comment: @Ron Maupin - Thanks for comments and explanations. Understood. 
I'll use IPv6 and that's it.
I'm just behind Cloudflare Proxy. Earlier there was the possibility to switch Ipv6 to IPv4. And now the default is only Ipv6. So I thought to myself that I could somehow convert it, because IPv4 is more readable. )))
Yes, I don’t have a deep understanding of networks, that’s why I asked.

Comment: It was closed because you asked on the wrong SE site. You ask about network protocol theory on [networkengineering.se]. Also: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Comment: see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49516679/6801443

Comment: @SeanF Thanks for the Answer, I saw this snippet. It will not works with full IPv6 address.

Comment: The IPv6 address must be in a format that corresponds to one of the translation/conversion protocols.  You cannot convert all IPv6 addresses, only those derived from IPv4 using a protocol of some sort.

Answer (score 2):

You can't convert IPv4 to IPv6, or the other way around. They are completely different things. It's like converting a telephone number to a street address: There *may* be come cases where there's a 1:1 mapping, or a 1:n mapping, but there's no guarantee.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but from my small knowledge it should be convertable.

Comment: Then I'm sorry but your small knowledge is wrong ;-). If you can post some more details about why you think it's possible, we might be able to explain more.